# How can I reset my progress in Angry Birds on iPhone?

Tags: angry-birds, ios

Is it possible to reset the game progress, as if the levels were never achieved (ie they are all locked) in the game Angry Birds on iPhone?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uninstall, and reinstall the game. This will clear your saved data and reset the game.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Angry Birds on your apps, then reinstall it - it will erase the data and start over.